# How to create such a xsd

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

I have a xml file that looks like this:

```
<Summary>
  <Persons>
    <Status>
      <Active value="false" text="Active" />
      <Inactive value="false" text="Inactive" />
    </Status>
   <Language>
      <Dutch value="false" text="" />
      <EnglishUK value="false" text="" />
      <EnglishUS value="false" text="" />
      <German value="false" text="" />
      <French value="false" text="" />
  </Language>
 </Persons>
 <Roles>
  <Status>
   <Active value="false" text="" />
   <Inactive value="false" text="" />
  </Status>
  <AssignedUsers>
   <m10 value="false" text="" />
   <b10and50 value="false" text="" />
   <x50 value="false" text="" />
  </AssignedUsers>
 </Roles>
</Summary>
```

i created a xsd from this xml using a online xsd generator:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Summary">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Persons">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Status">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Active">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Inactive">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Anonymous">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Yes">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="No">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="Language">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Dutch">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="EnglishUK">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="EnglishUS">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="German">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="French">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Roles">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Status">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Active">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Inactive">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="AssignedUsers">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="m10">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="b10and50">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="x50">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:simpleContent>
                      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="value"/>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="text"/>
                      </xs:extension>
                    </xs:simpleContent>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The problem is that each time i insert a new element into the Persons/Status or for example into the Roles/AssignedUsers, my validation failes.
What i want is a schema to validate the parent elements, like Person/Status and Roles/Status and the rest, but the child elements like '' don't need to be present, but if they are present, they must have the attributes 'value' and 'text'.
How to create such a schema, some help will be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation fails because you have not specified any of the elements as optional so, all of them become mandatory. Try adding `minOccurs="0"` to the elements that are optional.

For eg. I changed

```
<xs:element name="Anonymous" minOccurs="0">
```

and your sample xml was validated without errors

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i don't understand it fully. Are you saying that by adding the minOccurs="0", i can remove all the elements from xsd that belong to the child elements in my xml(the info belonging to the elements with 'value' and 'text' attribute)?...and what about the validation of the 'value' and 'text' attributes in my child elements? how can i then validate them?